# fstream doesn't write on file until endl

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to define this inline function. It would create a decision tree (a particoular binary tree used in operations research).

This is the code:

```
inline void printTreeFile(int* i_node,int* j_node,int* q_infr,int* value,int nStart,int level,std::fstream& tree)
{       int spazi=0,len,stop;   
        for(int actual_level=0;actual_level<level;actual_level++)
            {spazi+=9;
            if(i_node[actual_level]==0)
                len=1;
            else
                len=(int)log10(i_node[actual_level])+1;
            spazi+=len;
            if(j_node[actual_level]==0)
                len=1;
            else
                len=(int)log10(j_node[actual_level])+1;
            spazi+=len;
            if(q_infr[actual_level]==0)
                len=1;
            else
                len=(int)log10(q_infr[actual_level])+1;
            spazi+=len;
            }
        if(value[level]==0)
            {
            tree<<"-->("<<i_node[level]<<","<<j_node[level]<<","<<q_infr[level]<<"=1)";
            tree<<endl;
            for(int i=0;i<spazi;i++)
                tree<<" ";
            tree<<"-->("<<i_node[level]<<","<<j_node[level]<<","<<q_infr[level]<<"=0)";
            }
        else
            tree<<"-->("<<i_node[level]<<","<<j_node[level]<<","<<q_infr[level]<<"=1)";
        //cin>>stop;
}
```

The `std::fstream& tree` is defined in main as:

```
fstream tree;                       
remove("tree");
tree.open("tree",ios::out|ios::app);
```

I don't understand why the file `tree` is empty until is executed the command `tree<<endl;`

I need to see how the tree evolve itself without waiting for that command...anyone know a solution to this problem? **thanks to all that will answer!**

Comment: The stream has a buffer. You have to call flush() to enforce a write. std::endl adds a '\n' and calls flush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `endl` both outputs a newline *and* forces a buffer flush, which is why you're seeing it at that point.

File streams, unless you modify their properties, are fully buffered so you won't see anything until the buffer is full or you explicitly flush it.

This can be done with an `endl` (assuming you want a newline sent first), via `ostream::flush`, or when closing the file.

Probably the easiest fix is to add `tree.flush();` as the last line in your function.

---

And, as an aside given the commonality of some of those lines, I'd considering refactoring it to make it more readable, first a helper function:

```cpp
inline void outLine(std::fstream& tree, int *inode,
    int *jnode, int *qinfr, int level, int val)
{
    tree << "-->(" << i_node[level] << "," << j_node[level]
        << "," << q_infr[level] << "=" << val << ")";
}
```

Then calling that helper function, which makes the code a little cleaner (includes using string constructor to get rid of loop):

```cpp
if (value[level] == 0) {
    outLine (tree, i_node, j_node, q_infr, level, 1);
    tree << '\n' << std::string(spazi, ' ');
    outLine (tree, i_node, j_node, q_infr, level, 0);
} else {
    outLine (tree, i_node, j_node, q_infr, level, 1);
}
tree.flush();
```

Keep in mind the *reason* why files tend to be fully buffered while standard output is line buffered. Most files you don't care about until the job is done so full buffering is more efficient.

That's obviously not the case in *this* scenario but flushing more often than necessary will generally slow your code down.

If, as you say, this is just debug code, you can forget about refactoring or the speed penalty of  unnecessary flushing.

Comment: The reason that I'm trying to print in file this tree is for simple debug! When I'll want that this code run fast, I will not use this function ;)

Comment: No probs, @LovaJ., my other advice (on refactoring) has also been rendered moot by your comment. I'll leave it in but with the caveat that it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: file.close() did it for me